# how to implement IEEE 754 floating point subtraction in hardware?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754, subtraction

I searched the google and with no luck to find the answer of what I'm looking for.

Imagine these 2 numbers in base 2:

```
A = 1.0001 * e-4
B = 1.001 * e-6
```

So to subtract these 2 numbers we need to shift the 2end one 2 bits right, to have the same exponents. So now we have:

```
A = 1.0001 * e-4
B = 0.001001 * e-4
```

Now our exponents are the same and we should do subtraction for significands, which means:

```
  1.000100
- 0.001001
----------
  0.111011
```

Then we do the normalization and rounding process on the result. As a human we know how to deal with this subtraction, but what about HW? Does it use any special algorithm for making negative the `B` number (algorithm like 2's complement just like what we do for Integers)? This question is also valid when we want to do `A+B` but the `B` is a negative number.

Comment: If you know how it can be done in software, you **might** be able to turn that into hardware. Just note that this is not something simple. It is extremely complicated to get right, even in software, let alone in hardware.

Comment: No the problem is not about hardware or software, the problem is how to implement it. But I used HW word to insist that I am not talking about a `C` or `C++` program! I'm talking about an implementation from scratch with logics like `XOR`, `AND`, `NOT` and etc...

Comment: It is not trivial, but doable in software (machine code), even if you rule out instructions like `DIV` or `MUL`. There are existing libraries, take a look at them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to implement IEEE 754 floating point subtraction in hardware?

To be clear: IEEE 754 does not dictate how HW must perform a subtraction, only that given 2 inputs and rounding mode what the results must be.  The HW is a black box in the middle where a [miracle occurs](https://www.google.com/search?q=then+a+miracle+occurs&client=opera&hs=vyZ&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikntu3nNDXAhUm1oMKHezLD7sQsAQIJQ&biw=1474&bih=785).

---

Sample HW subtract algorithm:

Assume `N=8` bit significand, same sign for `a b` (else use addition),  and `|a| >= |b| > 0` (else swap operands).  Bit `x` is 0 or 1.

```
  1.xxxxxxx e AA
- 1.xxxxxxx e BB
```

Use `N+2` wide register. Find shift needed `AA - BB`. The shift will leave some of the `b` bits in the `N+2` register, and some to the "right".

```
  1.xxxxxxx_00     e AA
- 0.00001xx_xx xxx e AA
```

From the `xxx` shifted out, set a "borrow bit c" to are *any of them* 1?

```
             c <-- Initial borrow bit                    
  1.xxxxxxx_00 
- 0.00001xx_xx
```

---

Now perform the subtraction in the usual fashion.

To ease the function explanation, consider 2 cases: no initial shift/shift, even though HW would use a single common path.

```
  // Result with no shift.  Initial borrow bit 'c' is then zero.
  0.1111111_00 Max value
  0.0000000_00 Min-value  (a == b)
```

The result is shifted left and the exponent decremented until the lead bit is 1.  The subtraction is *exact*.  A zero result is handled specially (not shown).

---

In case 2, with shifting, 'c' is 0 or 1.

```
  // Result with shift
  1.1111110_11 Max value.
  0.1111111_1x Lowest-values.
```

If the lead bit is 0, the result is shifted left and exponent decremented. It is the lowest-values sub-cases that oblige a `N+2` instead of a `N+1` register to get the rounding (below) correct.

---

Now rounding occurs. First the `s` and `c` bit are or'ed (is either one?) to form the new `C`.  Various [rounding modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) like up, down, truncate, toward infinity and the popular "round to nearest with ties to even" can be deduced solely from the sign, `o`, `r` and `C`.  The result is exact when `r` and `C` are zero.

```
          o rs c
  1.xxxxxxx_xx c
  -->
  1.xxxxxxx_x  C
```

Now add the round bit `R`.

```
  1.xxxxxxx
  0.000000R
```

This sum may result in `10.0000000`.  In which case the result is shifted right and the exponent incremented.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I still did not understand how did you do the subtraction step. Did you use a 2's-complement-like algorithm to make a negative number and then do the addition? This is exactly my problem which I can not understand. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MA With `a-b`, FP uses [sign magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) so it is trivial to change the sign of a value by changing 1 bit.  If the operands signs do not match, negate `b` and call the addition routine/HW.  If the operands are `a < b`, then do `-(b - a)`.  Then subtraction  is like [primary school subtraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtraction#The_teaching_of_subtraction_in_schools), in base 2.  The core part of HW subtraction is sign-less.  No 2's complement involved.

Answer (score 0):

hmmmmm ... such is just as this question, needs accuracy in each detail, otherwise it'll fail ...

sorry, had difficulties with the formatting for LF and the citations .. :-(

```
Imagine these 2 numbers in base 2:
A = 1.0001 * e-4 
B = 1.001 * e-6
So to subtract these 2 numbers we need to shift the 2end one 2 bits right, 
to have the same exponents. So now we have:
```

!! 2 bits !!

```
A = 1.0001 * e-4
B = 0.001001 * e-4
```

!! shouldn't it be !!:

B = 0.01001 * e-4

```
Now our exponents are the same and we should do subtraction for 
significands, which means:

  1.000100
- 0.001001
----------
  0.111011
```

!! and acc. to the correction above !!:

```
  1.000100
- 0.010010
----------
  0.110010
```

reg.

b.